# SQL - Trying to group by each bit datatype change

Tags: sql

Suppose my data looks like this:

```
    Success TimeSYStz
    ------- ----------------------------------
    0       2020-04-24 09:04:17.4650558 -07:00
    0       2020-04-24 08:33:42.0242673 -07:00
    1       2020-04-24 08:03:47.0951466 -07:00
    1       2020-04-24 07:32:50.3835168 -07:00
    1       2020-04-24 07:02:28.6166144 -07:00
    1       2020-04-24 06:30:46.0713615 -07:00
```

I would like to group by the Success bit and display only the first occurrence of each row. the bit goes back and forth from 0 and 1 all the time but i just want the first time it changes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0. So I would want it to display like this:

```
    Success TimeSYStz
    ------- ----------------------------------
    0       2020-04-24 08:33:42.0242673 -07:00
    1       2020-04-24 06:30:46.0713615 -07:00
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide better sample data that shows the `success` value changing back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select id, TimeSYStz
from (select t.*, lag(success) over (order by TimeSYStz) as prev_success
      from t
     ) t
where prev_success is null or prev_success <> success;
```